# how do I print an integer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
 @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!


@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {

var age = textBox.text.toInt()

var Years = age! * 7

    result.text = "your cat is "+ catYears + "cat years old"//cat years is an int who do i print it
}
```

so after turning textBox into an integer how do i print it in integer form.

Comment: you can't down rate it off an assumption

Comment: Just `println(catYears)`. Or get fancy: `println("Cat Years: \(catYears)")`

Comment: `text = "your cat is \(catYears) old."`. I recommend reading the [swift book](https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l).

Comment: i already new of this but i was trying to see if there were any other ways of doing it like if it was a c rooted language

Comment: wait then who down voted it

Comment: Re-evalate the word "can't", in "You can't down rate it off an assumption". Sure can but the down vote you are referring to I didn't. But it would help if you would read the question from the top and make sure it is consistent, complete and askig the correct question.

Comment: thanks zaph your method worked

Comment: Now I am surprised, I became convinced that I had answered the wrong question. Really.

Comment: Can't see a variable called catYears.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
result.text = "your cat is \(Years) cat years old"
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two basic ways:

```
result.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) years old."

result.text = "Your cat is " + catYears.description + " years old."
```

You can also use `NSNumberFormatter`, which supports more complex features like thousandths separators and so on:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.hasThousandSeparators = true
let catYearsString = formatter.stringFromNumber(catYears)

result.text = "Your cat is " + catYearsString! + " years old."
```